# how to do a rolling regression in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy

I have the following code (it is not efficient as it is in a loop).

```
from scipy.stats import linregress

results =[]

for pos in range(126, len(data)) :
        results.append(linregress(data.a.iloc[(pos-126):pos], data.b.iloc[(pos-126):pos])[0])
```

How to rewrite this code in a more efficient form? Is it possible to do a rolling apply?

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up doing this in a loop, not the best solution. Clearly not a good solution although it works.

Any better idea please!

```
grouped = full_sample.groupby('ID')

df = pd.DataFrame()
for name, group in grouped:
    a=[]
    if len(group) > 126:
        for pos in range(126, len(group)) :
            a.append(linregress(group.x.iloc[(pos-126):pos], group.y.iloc[(pos-126):pos])[0])
        data= pd.DataFrame(a, index= (group.index.get_level_values(0).unique())[126:] ).assign(ID=name).set_index('ID', append=True)
df.append(data)
```

Thanks.